# How setContentScalefactor can be used for using Ipad Retina images in Ipad

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

In order to use IpadRetina images in Ipad,I have set content scale factor to 0.5 ,using screen to design size ratio. But then is it like I need to use setScale(factor) on every CCSprite I used in the game? I thought scaling will be done automatically based on the factor set in setContentScaleFactor.
Is there any reason Why scale factor is not set in initWithTexture ? or what are the complexities and complications for doing this ?

I added CCNode::setScale(0.5f); in "initWithTexture" and it works just fine , quickly I got to know how my IpadRetina resources would appear in Ipad . yes scale factor is hard coded as of now.

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Try setting the content scale factor to 2.0 only once in App Delegate. What do you see?

Comment: got it working by setting it to 1.0f , because I was setting design size for each device , so using art of IpadRetina , I had to set design size for IpadRetina Only , but I was setting it for Ipad